# Play 2.5, Scala, compile-time DI: crash when using Java controller, app.requestHandler is not a JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.12 with compile-time DI, and I'd like to use a Java controller (from [play-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j)). Using the controller fails with the following error:

```
scala.MatchError: Right((play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3@635c42c6,play.api.DefaultApplication@53dff0a2)) (of class scala.util.Right)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:93)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:163)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
```

After digging for a while, I found [JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.12/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/HttpRequestHandler.scala#L189-L199), which is supposed to be used by default for the `application.requestHandler`, as noted in [#5357](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5357) / implemented in [#5631](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5631). It seems that this is only the case when using run-time DI, but not when using compile-time DI: in this case it's just a [DefaultHttpRequestHandler](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.12/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Application.scala#L253).

To reproduce this in a small example, I took the `play-scala` and `play-scala-compile-di-with-tests` example projects and added a simple Java controller to each of them. The diff is [here for `play-scala`](https://github.com/lrytz/play-scala/compare/master...lrytz:javaController?expand=1) and [here for `play-scala-compile-di-with-tests`](https://github.com/lrytz/play-scala-compile-di-with-tests/compare/master...lrytz:javaController?expand=1). Using `sbt run` and then `curl localhost:9000/hi` works with run-time DI, but fails with compile-time DI, same error as above.

I think I could override the `httpRequestHandler` which is injected into the `Application` in my components assembly (I'm using MacWire)

```
override lazy val httpRequestHandler: HttpRequestHandler = wire[JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler]
```

But then I have to provide values of types `HttpFilters` and `JavaHandlerComponents`, which I'm not sure how to get.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some play experts offline, it seems that using a Java controller in a Scala play app is a rather exotic thing to do. While it's certainly possible to create a `JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler`, it requires instantiating quite a lot of Java play functionality (in a Scala play app).

The fact that the [play-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j) Scala example in their README.md does uses a Java controller unfortunate. Instead, one could call `pac4j` directly without using `play-pac4j`.